# Connecting Python & SQLalchemy and Flask via URI

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am hoping to run some database queries via my Flask application running in Python.

I have created an init for defining both SQLalchemy and flask within Python.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///new_db'
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
```

When I print my db variable I get the following '< SQLAlchemy >'

And it is here that it should also include the PostgreSQL db that it has been linked to via our Database URI.

In PostgreSQL, my database is titled as we see in the URI (new_db) and contains a table.

This is following the instructions of the tutorial I am working with, Maybe there is furthermore initialization that is needed for the URI?

I have tried setting the context for the SQL alchemy, but to no avail.

Comment: The db variable is an object. It's not meant to be printed. You should print `app.config`

Comment: Ok, I have tried that.. cool I can see all the configurations in one place.

Comment: But the point im making with the print is that It should be connected succesfully with the PostgreSQL database, but for some reason the URI link is not functioning.

Comment: According to what? As the answer below indicates, you're not currently doing anything with the database, such as query or create any tables... Printing configs and db variables doesn't actually make any connection

Comment: I see your point, The tutorial I was following had when printed the db variable I < SQLAlchemy  <postgresql linked here>. However When I try I just get <SQLAlchemy> and the postgresql link is omitted. When I run db.session.execute(SELECT * FROM db) I get the runtime error that I am working outside of the application context. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, so run that within an app context, such as `GET /all` Flask route